# Write a static synchronized method (wait for a result from thread)

Tags: java, multithreading, static, deadlock, synchronized

I have a problem with a task. Namely, we must write a class, which is called from Threads. One of the methods is:

```
public static synchronized void waitForResults() {

}
```

So the Master-Thread calls this method, and then the Master-Thread triggers an other Thread, that new work is to be done. How can I tell the Master-Thread that he sleep, while the Worker-Thread works?

Comment: `Master-Thread triggers an other Thread` By this do you mean that the another thread is started within `waitForResults`?

Answer (score 3):

Using the `wait()` and the `notify()` mechanism. Every java object posses those methods. A mechanism block a thread until some condition is met.

For exampe, if your main thread calls another thread that will change the value of the `result` variable. Then, you could `wait` on the `result` until it gets `notified` by some other thread:

```
private static StringBuilder result= new StringBuilder();

public static void mainThreadWork() {
    new WorkerThread().start();
    synchronized (result) {
        System.out.println(result.toString()); //prints ""
        result.wait();
        System.out.println(result.toString()); //prints "modified"
    }
}

private static class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(result) {
            result.append("modified");
            result.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

What happens: when a thread calls a `wait` on some object, it yields a CPU to other Threads and (as the method name says) waits for another thread to send a `notify` signal on that thread. `notify` yields a CPU to the thread that was waiting on that object.

Some rules must be respected, for example, `wait()` and `notify()` must be invoked inside a `synchronized` block.

---

Since Java 1.5 there are more abstract levels of synchronization and wait-notify mechanisms, so you could check java's `concurrent` [library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). It offers you to lock and wait for the object on more abstract object-like level:

```
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
```

So instead of `synchronized` blocks and `waits` and `notifies` you could just:

```
public static void mainThreadWork() {
    lock.lock();

    new WorkerThread().start();
    System.out.println(result.toString()); //prints ""
    condition.await();
    System.out.println(result.toString()); //prints "modified"

    lock.unlock();
}
```

And in the `WorkerThread`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    lock.lock();

    result.append("modified");
    condition.singal();

    lock.unlock();
}
```